# Calling function from function in class not working in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have a class with a bunch of functions. For some reason, I can't call a function within a function. My main function where I need to call another function. That doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
        # do some stuff

        self.cleanup()
        return

    def cleanup(self):
        # do some stuff
```

The cleanup function never gets called. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: This isn't reproducible. Are you sure the cleanup function isn't getting called, or that your control flow itself isn't the issue here?

Comment: without seeing how `parsed` is being set , i doubt someone will be able to help here. you can do one thing add an `else` and print something there for checking if parse is true at that stage of execution.

Comment: From where you got the `parsed` value?

Comment: I don't know if it's control flow or not. If I get rid of the return the parse function runs to completion but cleanup never gets called. As it is, the parse function ends at return and cleanup isn't called.

Comment: In that case, it isn't called because `code_num` is greater than 24. This is an issue with your data.

Comment: Magic 8-ball says `code_num` is a string.

Comment: Nope, its a number. Besides, I got rid of the `if parsed` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @miradulo from where  `code_num` came?

Answer (score -1):

If parsed value `True` its calling the function

```
class MySpider(object): 
    def parse(self, response):
        # do some stuff
        parsed = True
        if parsed:
            self.cleanup()
            return
        else:
            print 'parsed is False/None' 
    def cleanup(self):
        # do some stuff
        print "called"

MySpider().parse('response')
```

`Output: called`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I showed that `cleanup()` called properly if `parsed` is not `None` or `False`. If this isn't the answer I am afraid this question doesn't need an answer.